# Ansible inventory: replace issues

Tags: ansible

I have an inventory like this:

```
[all:vars]
env_cidr_prefix='172.25'
antother_var="foo"

[VPN_SERVER]
vpn-server ansible_host="{{ env_cidr_prefix}}.0.1"
```

During ansible playbook, the inventory holds only private ip address. 
I wan't to replace the content of `"ansible_host="` with the public ip

Example of a playbook:

```
- name: grab the vpn public_ip
  set_fact: PUBLIC_IP="{{ instance_eip.public_ip }}"
  when: inventory_hostname |search("vpn-server")

- name: update inventory with the vpn public ip
  replace:
     path: "{{ inventory_file }}"
     regexp: "{{ ansible_host }}"
     replace: "{{ PUBLIC_IP }}"
  when: inventory_hostname |search("vpn-server")
```

if

```
ansible_host="172.25.0.1"
```

the replace module will work correctly.

but this fails

```
ansible_host="{{ env_cidr_prefix}}.0.1"
```

debug output:

```
ok: [vpn-server] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "after": null,
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": false,
            "before": null,
            "content": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "encoding": "utf-8",
            "follow": false,
            "force": null,
            "group": null,
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "path": "/home/toluna/ansible/openvpn/env.properties",
            "regexp": "172.25.0.11",
            "remote_src": null,
            "replace": "1.1.1.1",
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "validate": null
        }
    },
    "msg": ""
}
```

Note, I cant use the `add_host` module since the playbooks are running in different stages

Is there a better way to do it ? 
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don’t fully understand the scenario. Why replacing the inventory with add_host is not an option but it is replacing the ip address in that way you want? If you have different stages, why not using different inventory files?

Comment: @imjoseangel I use different roles for each stage. creating aws instances is one role  and the vpn-server is another role. All of these stages run via Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after testing it I guess I understand what are you trying to achieve.

Several parts here:

The inventory file is like this:

```
vpn-server ansible_host="{{ env_cidr_prefix}}.0.1"
```

And you are trying to replace `172.25.0.1` literal which doesn't exist in your file. You have `"{{ env_cidr_prefix}}.0.1"` and not `172.25.0.1`.

Options:

1. If you want to replace that way, you can use a Jinja2 file in your role, replace the variable and the inventory file the same way you are trying.
2. Override the /etc/hosts file of your Jenkins (I really don't like too much) and play with the host name.
3. Play with your hosts variable in the playbook like:

Hosts Playbooks:

```
- name : Test
  hosts: "{{ variable_vpn_ip | default('vpn-server') }}"
```

And call it reading from a variable that you will change ad-hoc or:

```
ansible-playbook play.yml -e "variable_vpn_ip=172.25.0.1"
```